# Return to Top of Form in InfoPath

Tags: sharepoint-2013, infopath2010

I found this SharePoint way to return to the top of the page [here](https://sectorlearning.wordpress.com/2012/06/25/sharepoint-2010-how-to-create-a-return-to-top-button-on-a-wiki-page/). Does anyone know of a way to integrate this into an InfoPath form that resides on SharePoint?

Comment: I don't think this is possible.  A workaround I have seen is to create a hidden field at the top of your form and then create an Access key to it, e.g., Alt + X.  Although this stinks for a typical end user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a limited work around using `jQuery`. I downloaded the `.js` file from here:

[jquery-3.1.0.slim.min.js](https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.slim.min.js)

Saved it to my SharePoint Site and then embedded the following to the Page housing the InfoPath web part.

```
<script src="https://yoursharepointURL.com/SiteAssets/Scripts/jquery-3.1.0.slim.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
function openLinkInSameWindow() {

 $('a[target="_blank"]').removeAttr('target'); 
}
 _spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("openLinkInSameWindow");

</script>
```

Then in the InfoPath form I called the script using the following URL

```
https://yoursharepointURL.com/SitePages/Page.aspx#top
```

It's been working well since!